# Arraylist user selector

Tags: c#, arraylist

Okay, so I am trying to make a simple secret Santa program, they type in their name, it then removes them from the arraylist, and randomizes the arraylist and outputs the text to a text box, or should I say, I need it to.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ArrayList NameSel = new ArrayList();
    NameSel.Add("name1");
    NameSel.Add("name2");
    NameSel.Add("name3");;
    if (textBox1.Text == "name1")
    {
        NameSel.Remove("name1");
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randoms = rand.Next(NameSel.Count);
        string textbox = NameSel[randoms];
        textBox2.Text = textbox;
    }
```

The problem lies at `textbox`, specifically "`NameSel[randoms];`".

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I don't work with arraylists at all, for this I usually a string, for example

```
string[] names = new string[]
{
     "name1",
     "name2",
     "name3",
};
```

And I tested, and that works, but as far as I am aware, I cant use `stringname.remove("name1")` or any equivalent, so I am out of my comfort zone, Any help that doesn't massively edit the original code is appreciated!

Comment: Don't paste in screenshots of errors. It's very inconvenient for those of us reading your question, and it's not searchable. Pleas paste the text of the error message into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't use ArrayList!**

An ArrayList could have *anything* in it. You want a generic `List<string>` instead. It works almost exactly the same, but will only let you put strings in it and therefore won't make you do casting.

Additionally, a much better and simpler method for assigning secret santa names is to shuffle the list once (and **only** once, so don't this as part of your existing method), and then assign everyone to the person who comes after them in the list (or before, if you prefer). Also assign the person at the end of the list to the person at the beginning. This ensures that everyone has exactly one person assigned to them, and everyone is assigned to someone.

Comment: Thank you, it worked very well, and was a quick edit, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your error output is very telling, it's stating you need a cast to a String if you are attempting to pull a value from your list and assign it to a String reference variable.

I.E. `string textbox = (string)NameSel[randoms];`

You should also be able to take advantage of generics, when declaring your ArrayList in the first place. new `ArrayList<String>()`. This way the program knows you want a collection of strings vs objects(then cast isn't necessary).

Comment: Question is tagged with C# tag.